# How to construct Kendo Grid with Angular models

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I am trying to have my **kendo** options in *angularjs* model and the grid is not loading.
I would like to store the options like (`vm.test.mainGridOptions={}`), which is not working. Whereas if the options are stored like `vm.mainGridOptions={}` it's working.

Failing version:
https://dojo.telerik.com/iPiTIVOY/2

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs is throwing an error in console, at least in that URL

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'mainGridOptions' of undefined

This sounds like a typo. You should check that "test" variable not to be undefined.

---

Bonus: [ngCloak directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template
> from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
> form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
> the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.